# create list for dropdown with value from relationed table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

My model Product return something like this

- id = 1
- name = Product Name
- category_id = 101
- category = array

  - id = 101
  - name = electronics

and I need to use `lists()` to create something like this:

> lists("category.name", "id")

but it looks that this is impossible. How to create list for dropdown like this:

```
1 = electronics
2 = furniture
3 = cars
...
```

thanks a lot

Comment: Is 'Category' a model that belongs to 'Product'? If so, are you trying to list all categories, or just a subset of categories?

Comment: Product belongsTo Category and Category hasMany Product. Im trying to list products ids with category names belongs to each product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you did set up the right relations? Cause that is just what `lists()` usually does and it's far from impossible to create such a list.
It's quite hard to understand how you did design your Eloquent logic without your code, but here's how I would handle your situation, assuming you've already set up the `category_product` pivot table.
Given two models, `Product` and `Category`, I'd define these 2 relations cause, as far as I can get, a product can have several categories and a categories can be associated with several product :

```
class Product extends Model
{
   ////////
   public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
    }
   ////////
}
```

and

```
class Category extends Model
    {
       ////////
       public function products()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
        }
       ////////
    }
```

At this point, you're good to go, all you have to do in order to get your list is

```
Product::findOrFail($id)->categories->lists('name','id')
```

This will return an array holding all the categories associated with the given product

```
array:[
    1 => first-category
    2 => second-category
    3 => third-category
    ....
  ]
```

Note that with this set up it'll work the other way around as well, if you want to get a list of all the product that match a given category

```
Category::findOrFail($id)->products->lists('name','id')
```

At the very top of the answer I assumed you did set up a pivot table but, if you didn't, here's a quick tip:
within your products migration

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
        });

        Schema::create('category_product', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Then `migrate` and now everything is properly set up. Last but not least, if you are going to use this migration, you'll need to fix the relation in the model, which one is up to yours app logic: let's say the flow is create a new product -> choose the categories within the creation form, then you need to add `timestamps()` in the categories method

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category')->withTimeStamps();
```